# OpenCL: clAmdFft (OpenCL FFT lib from AMD) on NVIDIA GPUs

Tags: cuda, opencl, fft, gpgpu, amd-processor

Has anyone experiences with running the OpenCL FFT library from AMD (http://developer.amd.com/libraries/appmathlibs/pages/default.aspx) on NVIDIA GPUs?

I'm trying to port an existing algorithm from CUDA (with the most recent CUFFT) to OpenCL. The new code is running fine with an AMD GPU but not with my NVIDIA GPU. The NVIDIA GPU is recognized properly but the resulting array is zero all over without throwing any errors. By the way, the code runs also fine on an Intel Core i3 CPU. So my code seems to be fine.

AMD as well as NVIDIA seem to refuse support for this topic.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

My environment is a Windows 7 Professional x64 OS and I'm using the Visual Studio C++ Professional IDE with it's build-in x86 compiler.
The NVIDIA GPU is a GeForce GTX 560 Ti (MSI N560GTX-Ti Twin Frozr II/OC 1GB). The well working CPU is a Intel Core i3-2100 (2x3.1GHz) and than there is the Radeon HD 6850 (Sapphire Radeon HD 6850 1GB).
I tried compiling the code against the newest OpenCL releases of AMD, NVIDIA and Intel, with the same results and have of cause the newest developer drivers installed.

Here is my pretty basic sample code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <complex>  

#include <clAmdFft.h>  

#if defined (__APPLE__) || defined(MACOSX)  
    #include <OpenCL/opencl.h>  
#else  
    #include <CL/opencl.h>  
#endif  

// Typedef for complex field objects  
using namespace std;  
typedef std::complex<float> cl_compl_flt;   

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
          cl_uint width = 1024, height = 1024;                                                  // Field dimensions  
          cl_uint cl_platformsN = 0;                                                                                // Platform count  
          cl_platform_id *cl_platformIDs = NULL;                                                  // IDs of OpenCL platforms  
    cl_uint cl_deviceCount = 0;                                                                                // Device count  
    cl_device_id *cl_devices = NULL;                                                            // Device IDs  
          cl_int cl_err = 0;                                                                                                    // Buffer for error informations  
          cl_context cl_dev_context;                                                                                // Context  
          cl_command_queue cl_queue;                                                                                // Queue  
          clAmdFftSetupData fftSetupData;                                                                      // FFT setup data  
          clAmdFftPlanHandle fftPlan;                                                                                // FFT plan  
          clAmdFftDim fftDim = CLFFT_2D;                                                                      // FFT dimension  
          size_t fftSize[2];                                                                                                    // FFT size  
                    fftSize[0] = width;  
                    fftSize[1] = height;  
          cl_mem d_data;                                                                                                              // Device level data  
          cl_compl_flt* h_src;                                                                                          // Host level input data  
          cl_compl_flt* h_res;                                                                                          // Host level output data  

          // Allocate host memory  
          h_src = (cl_compl_flt*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt));  
          h_res = (cl_compl_flt*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt));  

          // Get source field  
          createPinholeField( h_src, width, height, 5 );  

          // Get FFT version  
          checkCL( clAmdFftInitSetupData(&fftSetupData) );  
          printf("Using clAmdFft %u.%u.%u\n",fftSetupData.major,fftSetupData.minor,fftSetupData.patch);  

          // Get available platforms  
          checkCL( clGetPlatformIDs ( 0, NULL, &cl_platformsN));  
          cl_platformIDs = (cl_platform_id*) malloc( cl_platformsN * sizeof(cl_platform_id));  
          checkCL( clGetPlatformIDs( cl_platformsN, cl_platformIDs, NULL) );  

          // Loop over platforms  
          for( cl_uint i = 0; i < cl_platformsN; i++)  
          {  
                    // Get number of available devices for this platform  
                    checkCL( clGetDeviceIDs( cl_platformIDs[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, NULL, NULL, &cl_deviceCount));  

                    // Skip platform if no device available  
                    if(cl_deviceCount < 1)  
                              continue;  

                    // Get available device IDs for this platform  
                    cl_devices = (cl_device_id*) malloc( cl_deviceCount * sizeof(cl_device_id));   
                    checkCL( clGetDeviceIDs( cl_platformIDs[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, cl_deviceCount, cl_devices, NULL));  

                    // Print platform name  
                    char platform_name[1024];  
                    checkCL( clGetPlatformInfo( cl_platformIDs[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 1024, &platform_name, NULL) );  
                    printf("\nCompute using OpenCl platfrom #%i [ %s ]\n", i,platform_name);  

                    // Loop over devices  
                    for( cl_uint j = 0; j < cl_deviceCount; j++)  
                    {  
                              // Print device name and type  
                              cl_device_type device_type;  
                              char device_name[1024];  
                              checkCL( clGetDeviceInfo( cl_devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME, 1024, &device_name, NULL) );  
                              checkCL( clGetDeviceInfo( cl_devices[j],CL_DEVICE_TYPE, sizeof(cl_device_type), &device_type, NULL) );  
                              printf("\n\tUsing OpenCl device #%i [ %s -- %s ]\n", j, device_name, getDevTypeString(device_type));  

                              // Create OpenCL context  
                              cl_context_properties cps[3] =   
                              {  
                                        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,   
                                        (cl_context_properties)cl_platformIDs[i],   
                                        0  
                              };  
                              cl_dev_context = clCreateContext( cps, cl_deviceCount, cl_devices, NULL, NULL, &cl_err);  
                              checkCL( cl_err);  

                              // Create command queue  
                              cl_queue = clCreateCommandQueue( cl_dev_context, cl_devices[j], CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &cl_err);  
                              checkCL( cl_err);  

                              // Create device buffer  
                              d_data = clCreateBuffer( cl_dev_context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt), NULL, &cl_err);  
                              checkCL( cl_err);  

                              // Setup FFT  
                              checkCL( clAmdFftSetup(&fftSetupData) );  

                              // Create FFT plan  
                              checkCL( clAmdFftCreateDefaultPlan( &fftPlan, cl_dev_context, fftDim, fftSize) );  

                              // Copy data from host to device  
                              clEnqueueWriteBuffer( cl_queue, d_data, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt), h_src, 0, NULL, NULL);  

                              // Execute FFT  
                              checkCL( clAmdFftEnqueueTransform( fftPlan, CLFFT_FORWARD, 1, &cl_queue, 0, NULL, NULL, &d_data, NULL, NULL) );  
                              clFinish( cl_queue);  

                              // Copy result from device to host  
                              checkCL( clEnqueueReadBuffer(cl_queue, d_data, CL_TRUE, 0, width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt), h_res, 0, NULL, NULL) );  
                              clFinish( cl_queue);  

                              // Save result  
                              char filename[512];  
                              sprintf( filename, "raw/result_%u_%u_in.raw",i,j);  
                              printf("\tSave result to \"%s\" ", filename);  
                              saveRawData( h_res, filename, width, height, true);  
                              printf("\n");  

                              // Free FFT plan  
                              checkCL( clAmdFftDestroyPlan( &fftPlan) );  

                              // Free FFT  
                              checkCL( clAmdFftTeardown() );  

                              // Free device memory  
                              checkCL( clReleaseMemObject(d_data) );  

                              // Release OpenCL context and queue  
                              checkCL( clReleaseCommandQueue( cl_queue ) );  
                              checkCL( clReleaseContext( cl_dev_context) );  
                    }   
                    // Free OpenCL devices  
                    free( cl_devices);  
          }  

          free( h_src);  
          free( h_res);  

          printf("\n\nPress any key ...");  
          getchar();  
          return 0;  
}
```

and the additional used functions ...

```
// Generate a pinhole  
void createPinholeField( cl_compl_flt* data, cl_uint width, cl_uint height, cl_uint radius)  
{  
          if(data==NULL)  
                    data = (cl_compl_flt*)malloc(width*height*sizeof(cl_compl_flt));  


          if(radius < 1)  
                    radius = (width>height)?height/2:width/2;  


          cl_float min_val = 0.0f;  
          cl_float max_val = 255.0f;  


          for(cl_uint y = 0; y < height; y++)  
        for(cl_uint x = 0; x < width; x++)  
                    {  
                              if ( ceil( sqrt( pow(x-width/2., 2.) + pow(y-height/2., 2.) )) <= radius )  
                              {  
                                        data[x+y*width].real(max_val);  
                                        data[x+y*width].imag(0.f);  
                              }  
                              else  
                              {  
                                        data[x+y*width].real(min_val);  
                                        data[x+y*width].imag(0.f);  
                              }  
                    }  
}  

// Save a cl_compl_flt array as an unsigned char raw image file  
void saveRawData( cl_compl_flt* char_array, const char* filepath, cl_uint width, cl_uint height, bool print_minmax )  
{  
          cl_float* abs_v = (cl_float*) malloc(width*height*sizeof(cl_float));   


          for( cl_uint i = 0; i < width*height; i++)  
                    abs_v[i] = abs(char_array[i]);  


          cl_float min = abs_v[0];  
          cl_float max = abs_v[0];  


          for( cl_uint i = 1; i < width*height; i++)  
          {  
                    if( abs_v[i] < min)  
                              min = abs_v[i];  
                    if( abs_v[i] > max)  
                              max = abs_v[i];  
          }  


          if( print_minmax)   
                    printf(" [min=%f , max=%f] ",min,max);  


          max *= .01f;  


          cl_uchar* temp = (cl_uchar*) malloc(width*height*sizeof(cl_uchar));  


          for( cl_uint i = 0; i < width*height; i++)  
                    temp[i] = 255*(cl_uchar)(( (cl_float)abs_v[i] - min) / ( max-min ));  


          FILE *pFile = NULL;  
          pFile=fopen(filepath,"wb");  
          fwrite(temp,1,width*height,pFile);  
          fclose(pFile);  
          free(abs_v);  
          free(temp);  
}  

// Check functions that return OpenCL error IDs.  
bool checkCL( cl_int oclErrorCode)  
{  
          if( oclErrorCode == CL_SUCCESS)  
                    return true;  
          else  
          {  
                    printf("\n\nAn OpenCL related error occured!\nError ID #%d\nPress ENTER to exit the program...\n\n", oclErrorCode);  
                    getchar();  
                    exit( oclErrorCode);  
                    return false;  
          }  
}  

// Get device type as string  
char* getDevTypeString(cl_device_type type)  
{  
          switch(type)  
          {  
          case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU:  
                    return "CPU";  
                    break;  
          case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU:  
                    return "GPU";  
                    break;  
          case CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR:  
                    return "ACCELERATOR";  
                    break;  
          default:  
                    return "DEFAULT";  
                    break;  
          }  
}
```

I hope this helps to narrow down the problem.

P.S.: Images can be seen here: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/159149

Comment: According to [OpenCL FFT on both Nvidia and AMD hardware?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304268/opencl-fft-on-both-nvidia-and-amd-hardware), AMD's OpenCL FFT should also work on NVidia Hardware.  Alternatively you can try [ArrayFire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/opencl/c/)

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of moving this question off of the unanswered list...

According to [OpenCL FFT on both Nvidia and AMD hardware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304268/opencl-fft-on-both-nvidia-and-amd-hardware), The AMD OpenCL FFT should work on NVidia Hardware. However, NVIDIA does not support this library officially, and I doubt AMD does either, so I am not surprised that you don't get correct results.

As mentioned in a comment, [ArrayFire](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/opencl/c/) is probably a good cross-platform solution. There is a free version for single-GPU, non-commercial use so you can evaluate it.

Comment: Isn't ArrayFire FLOSS?!

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't when I answered this question 8 years ago.